# Remove saving notification when use python QGIS at startup

Tags: pyqgis

I try to run python at QGIS startup. The script :

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject

from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo

project = QgsProject.instance()

project.read(QFileInfo('D:/test/qgis/1.qgs'))
```

I save as startup.py in C:\Users\USER.qgis2\python. The project is successfully opened. There are two layer. A vector and a raster. But, there is a notification : "Do you want to save the current project?". If I click 'Save' or 'Discard', the 1.qgs is saved , and then there is a blank project. If I click 'Cancel', the 1.qgs is still opened.
It is disturb a lay user. While I don't want to close the project. I just want to load the project.

How do I remove this notification?

Comment: I think what is happening is that your `project.read` is happening before QGIS has initialised its usual initial project. So when it tries to do that, your project is there, so it asks if you want to save/cancel/etc your project just as it does when you load a new project from the menu. I suspect you'll have to be a bit trickier - maybe your startup code will have to wait for a signal that QGIS is done initialising and then read the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [@Spacedman](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/865/spacedman) is correct in that the *startup.py* script is read **before** QGIS loads a blank project. The [QgisInterface class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html) does contain an [initializationCompleted()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a6f1cc8be7d4e0b4c76c2806b78b3d8b0) signal which is emitted once QGIS has finished its initialisation process. We can then connect this to a function which can load your project:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.utils import iface

project = QgsProject.instance()

def load_project():
    project.read(QFileInfo('D:/test/qgis/1.qgs'))

iface.initializationCompleted.connect(load_project)
```

Comment: @mega - Most welcome, glad it worked :)