# List index out of range when put in startup.py on QGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I have the code :

```
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry
vl = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('pl')[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(vl)
```

When I type in console after loading QGIS, no error. But, when I put the code in startup.py, so automatically QGIS will execute the code in startup.py, I get error. The error : "list index out of range"

What is wrong for the code?

Comment: Generally it means you are calling something that doesn't exist.  So I assume when you have QGIS open and use the console, your object exists, but when you call your code in startup.py the object doesn't yet exist...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to preliminarily import the layer before calling it.

If `pl` is a shapefile:

```py
from qgis.core import *
layer =  QgsVectorLayer('C:/Users/path_to_shapefile/vector_layer.shp', 'pl' , "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
vl = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('pl')[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(vl)
```

If `pl` is a raster:

```py
from qgis.core import *
layer =  QgsRasterLayer('C:/Users/path_to_raster/raster_layer.tif', 'pl')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
vl = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('pl')[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(vl)
```

Comment: Nice answer! I would just like to add that when adding any layers from the `startup.py` script, it is probably best to define a function which loads the layers and run this function when QGIS has finished the initialisation process as was asked in [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226298/remove-saving-notification-when-use-python-qgis-at-startup). Otherwise the annoying notification message appears :)

Comment: It is work. But, there is annoying notification as in this post : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226298/remove-saving-notification-when-use-python-qgis-at-startup. I can not combine the code to remove notification. Should I ask a new question?

Comment: @mega I think you are asking some help for a new topic. Assuming that it's not a duplicate of the question in the link that you shared, I suggest you accepting this answer (it seems it solved the error: *"list index out of range"*) and asking a new question.