# QGIS asks to save at startup?

Tags: python, pyqgis

I'm working in a project and i need to load some layers at startup.
I do it adding this code to startup file localted in the bin folder.

```
capa = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:32614&field=yeah:string(30)&index=yes', 'capita', "memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(capa)
```

This step is right, however, when i start qgis, it asks if i want to save, discard o cancel changes.
If i select save or discard, it creates a new project without my layers.
but if i chose to cancel changes, nothing else happens and my layers are there ok (and this is what i want)

Does anybody knows how to hide that prompt and let my layers to be loaded without ask me to save?

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: I think this post should help: [Remove saving notification when use python QGIS at startup](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226298/remove-saving-notification-when-use-python-qgis-at-startup)